# Basic scala syntax, which one is a new instance of a class?

Tags: scala

Hi can you please explain what the objects in the following code is called?

[[image: scala syntax[1]]

Namely, I know that "new location" is the instance of "location," (or is it "loc1" the instance of the class, "location"?)

So what is "new location" called? Is it an instance of the class, "location"?

And what is "location@99407c2"? Is it a unique identifier for the new instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, those question are relevant also to plain simple Java and are not Scala specific.

`new location` create new instance of your class, `loc1` hold the reference to the new class
 `location@99407c2` is the object toString (I think) -

[Read](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/getting-started-scala-repl-command-line-shell-options) [more](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/scala-tutorial-scala-repl-expressions.html) about Scala REPL